# Angular guide: different types of NgModules

Tags: angular, angular-routing, ng-modules

I was reading the Angular guide about [Guidelines for creating NgModules](https://angular.io/guide/module-types) and I could not understand the difference between **Routed** and **Routing** NgModules. In my apps I always used the "standard" (?) main module + routing module pair for features, and I now understand these are the Domain NgModule and the Routing NgModule. I could easily understand Service, Shared and Widget NgModule. I cannot understand at all the what, why and how of the Routed NgModule. Is someone able to shed some light? Thank you!

Comment: `loadChildren: () => import('./items/items.module').then(m => m.ItemsModule)` then ItemsModule is the Routed NgModule. ItemsRoutingModule imported into ItemsModule which defines routes within that module is a Routing NgModule. (or checkout the new docs angular.dev and go standalone and pretend NgModules don't exist)

Comment: But isn’t ItemsModule a Domain NgModule? It represents a feature and has declarations, and the Angular docs even say that a Routing NgModule is exactly the companion of a Domain NgModule… I still don’t understand I think 

Comment: Domain NgModule is kind of a dumb name. Typically domain is used as a term to describe an area of a business like purchasing versus production and within a domain you’d have many features like suppliers, orders, materials, production stages etc. The Domain NgModule is here used to mean a module with a top level component as opposed to a lazy loaded feature module. 90% of apps will be have 1 domain and should be split up into lazy loaded routed features. ItemsModule is lazy loaded routed feature.

Comment: I think I now understand, and can then agree it's a particular choice for a name! So "usually" apps are made of many Routed + Routing modules pairs, and one rarely sees a Domain NgModule as described in the Angular docs!